# Table shifting bug?

Tags: function-construction

I use *Mathematica* for calculation of coordinates in format `{x[t], y[t]}`. For this purpose, I wrote `Module` T`RAJ[x0,y0,tmin,tmax]`. When I try to output the results of two calculations with different x0, in a sigle way, like:

```
TRAJ[5, 460, 200, 202]
```

> ```
> {{0.005, 0.38322}, {0.005, 0.382836}, {0.005, 0.382453}}
> ```

```
TRAJ[35, 460, 200, 202]
```

> ```
> {{0.035, 0.38322}, {0.035, 0.382836}, {0.035, 0.382453}}
> ```

everything is ok, `y[t]` is same, just `x[t]` is different. But when I want to output same results in a `Table` (for further plotting), *Mathematica* give me "shifted" results without no reason:

```
Table[TRAJ[g, 460, 200, 202], {g, 5, 35, 30}]
```

> ```
> {{{0.005, 0.420867}, {0.005, 0.420671}, {0.005, 0.420475}},
>  {{0.035, 0.186067}, {0.035, 0.184697}, {0.035, 0.183327}}}
> ```

Now `x[t]` is different AND `y[t]` is "shifted".

Is there any way to avoid this wrong `Table` output? Or I just do something wrong?

```
d = 50*10^-6;
ρW = 1050;
ρO = 850;
g = 9.81;

μW = 1.002*10^-3;
μO = 7*10^-3;

εO = 2.5*8.854187*10^-12;
εW = 81*8.854187*10^-12;

λ = μW/μO ;

volumeW = N[1/6 Pi*d^3];
m = ρW*volumeW;    

TRAJ[x0_, y0_, tmin_, tmax_] := Module[{},
   ClearAll[ay, vy, vx, yBuoyancy, yDrag, xDrag, xForce, yForce, sol];
   ay[t_] := y''[t];
   vy[t_] := y'[t];
   ax[t_] := x''[t];
   vx[t_] := x'[t];

   yBuoyancy = -(ρW - ρO)*g*volumeW;
   yDrag = 3 Pi*μW*(λ + 2/3)/(λ + 1)*d*(-vy[t]);
   xDrag = 3 Pi*μW*(λ + 2/3)/(λ + 1)*d*(-vx[t]);
   xForce = 0;
   yForce = 0;   
  sol = Flatten[
   NDSolve[{m*ay[t] == yBuoyancy + yDrag + yForce, 
     m*ax[t] == xForce + xDrag, y[0] == y0*0.001, vy[0] == 0, 
     x[0] == x0*0.001, vx[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}]];
Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, {t, tmin, tmax }];
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Seconding @Öskå,  without your code there is nothing we can do to help you. Please add that to the question.

Comment: Added TRAJ module

Comment: Your code for `TRAJ` doesn't work as described. Please provide working code, or we can't help you.

Comment: Added constants

Comment: Your original question used a function with 4 arguments. The code you've added later defines a function of three arguments. They don't match. @Kuba had commented on this issue before. Always read the comments

Comment: I have an answer. Will post it if the question gets reopened. Way too many errors in there

Comment: @belisarius Now reopened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are using `Module` wrong.  It should start like this:

```
TRAJ[x0_, y0_, tmin_, tmax_] := 
 Module[{x, y, ay, ax, vy, vx, yBuoyancy, yDrag, xDrag, xForce, yForce, sol},
  ay[t_] := y''[t];
  (* the rest of your code *)
```

Second, [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) works by the mechanism of [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).  Refer to [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121) and especially WReach's concise example to see how this works.  The *global* value of `g` is being changed which affects the result of the computation.  You instead want only to vary a local value.  You can again use `Module` for that:

```
Module[{g},
  Table[TRAJ[g, 460, 200, 202], {g, 5, 35, 30}]
]
```

> ```
> {{{0.005, 0.38322}, {0.005, 0.382836}, {0.005, 0.382453}},
>  {{0.035, 0.38322}, {0.035, 0.382836}, {0.035, 0.382453}}}
> ```

Alternatively you could you a construct besides table, e.g. [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
TRAJ[#, 460, 200, 202] & /@ Range[5, 35, 30]
```

> ```
> {{{0.005, 0.38322}, {0.005, 0.382836}, {0.005, 0.382453}},
>  {{0.035, 0.38322}, {0.035, 0.382836}, {0.035, 0.382453}}}
> ```

While the behavior of `Table` may come as a shock to you it is actually a valuable aspect of the function and it should not be dismissed as a peculiarity.