# What to use instead of ReplaceAll to replace a parameter with a number before the evaluation of an integral?

Tags: replacement

This is probably very simple but I don't see the solution now. Let us say I have a variable e defined as

```
e=n
```

ReplaceAll can subsitute n with value 3 using

```
e/.n->3
```

The problem is when e is given by an integral of some function f[{n_}, r_] with n as a parameter

```
e=Integrate[f[{n}, r],{r, rmin, rmax}]
```

Then the use of

```
e/.n->3
```

will take too long if the integral in question is hard to evaluate and so, better would be FIRST to replace n with its numerical value and THEN evaluate the integral.

If e was defined as a function

```
e[n_]:=Integrate[f[{n}, r],{r, rmin, rmax}]
```

there would be no problem. But my function f depends on quite many definitions (using "n") I made earlier. It works ok but then in the end of my code there is a complicated f which makes the integration (i.e. evaluation of "e") too long - and I don't want to change all the definitions I made before.

What to do if I want to keep "e" as above, i.e. I don't want to define it as a function?

Comment: Oh, sure, you're right, I used another symbol, I forgot about that. Thanks, edited.

Comment: If you are not making functions, and `n` is eventually replaced by a number, why not simply define `n` beforehand?  E.g. `n=3;e=n`.

Comment: @2012rcampion Right, I should have noted that. I cannot use your solution because I will need to evaluate `e` for several values of `n`, (e.g. using Table).

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of: [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

The first method I recommended does not work properly.  I fooled myself because I have a `$PrePrint` definition by default.  However following your update I think you do not need `ReplaceAll`.  Instead try [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html):

```
e := Integrate[1/(x^3 + 1), {x, 0, n}];

Block[{n = 2.0}, e]
```

> ```
> 1.09
> ```

Not the use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) to keep the definition from evaluating early.

It happens that [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) uses a `Block`-like mechanism<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71342/table-shifting-bug/71353#71353)</sup> therefore you can also use:

```
Table[e, {n, 1`, 4`, 1`}]
```

> ```
> {0.835649, 1.09, 1.15445, 1.17814}
> ```

I recommend that you also read:

- [Expressions containing globally undefined symbols inside a function where they are defined](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)
- [Creating a Block from a list of rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31708/121)

Comment: +1. But, two or more levels of `Unevaluated` usually signal (to me), that `Unevaluated` is generally the wrong tool for the job (not in this particular case).

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the $E$ and added some motivation on why I do not want to define a function. To your answer - for some reason I am not gettin "1.09" as output but rather $\text{Unevaluated}\left[\int_0^{2.} \frac{1}{x^3+1} \, dx\right]$ Why is that?

Comment: @wondering You're right, my result only appears because I am using a `$PrePrint` definition.  I forgot to test this in a default configuration.  Sorry.  Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @wondering Please see the update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, this works. Actually this solution (with `SetDelayed` + `Table` came to my mind but because I have two parameters `m` and `n` from which only `n` one takes several values, `m` only one, I would have had anyway to define `m` beforehand as 2012rcampion suggested (or to make a Table[e,{n,nmin,nmax},{m,m0,m0}], but that is not very good). I think the best solution for this situation is a combination of your two suggestions, with `Block` and `Table`, i.e.: `Block[{m=1}, Table[e, {n, 1, 5}]]` +1

Comment: @wondering I'm glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.  Did you try Albert Retey's `blockrules` from [(3864)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3864/121)?  How about my `blockSet` from [(69590)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69590/121)?  Either of these may make your task easier.  Let me know if you have trouble applying them.